# Phonegap the sdk build tools revision (19.0.0) is too low for project

Tags: android, cordova

I am beginning the learning path to Phonegap/Cordova. I can get an application to run in Google Chrome using Ripple, however I am stymied trying to get a local build. I have looked exhaustively for these errors "the sdk build tools revision (19.0.0) is too low for project" or "[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.0" and get numerous questions with vague or non existent answers.

My operating system is Windows Vista 64. I have checked the Android SDK using Android SDK manager. The current build tools installed are 20. No other incarnations of the Build-tools are installed. Where is [getbuildtools] getting its details from ?

I have checked all the paths and variables: ANT_HOME=C:\Apache Ant\apache-ant-1.9.4, JAVA_HOME (JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21), ANDROID_SDK=C:\Android SDK\sdk.

I went through a simple exercise of 
cordova create test
cd test
cordova platform add android
cordova build

There the error presents itself. I tried a similar exercise with Phonegap instead of Cordova and repeatedly get the same error. I tried setting the AndroidManifest.xml to 
 no different, changed the numbers to 18, nothing.

I installed Ant separately, no difference.

Frustrated beyond belief, do I need to uninstall Android SDK & reinstall ?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem.

> The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.0) is too low for project
>   'MyProject'. Minimum required is 19.1.0

I just needed to open Android SDK Manager, selected and installed a later version (21.1.1). No need to reinstall and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Android SDK and Eclipse, removed all residual files. Rebooted. Reinstalled the Eclipse version of the SDK, put in 19.1 and 20 target platforms and now it all works. I would still like to know where [getbuildtools] gets its information from as then it would assist in tracking down the problem rather than resorting to this drastic measure.